# Numpy fill_diagonal pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any chance to do `np.fill_diagonal` on PySpark dataframe?

I have a pivot table that diagonal consist of Null value, and I need to replace them into `0` value. But I got a problem when I do this to my PySpark dataframe.

So this is my script

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    Row(product_1='Renault', product_2='City', distance=0.0),
    Row(product_1='City', product_2='Renault', distance=0.3),
    Row(product_1='Maruti', product_2='Toyota', distance=0.2),
    Row(product_1='Honda', product_2='Mitsubishi', distance=0.1),
    Row(product_1='Tesla', product_2='Esemka', distance=0.6),
    Row(product_1='Supra', product_2='Renault', distance=0.0)])

schema = schema = StructType([
   StructField("product_1", StringType(), True),
   StructField("product_2", StringType(), True),
   StructField("distance", FloatType(), False)])

df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df_spark_res = df_spark.groupBy("product_1").pivot("product_2").agg(F.expr("first(distance)"))
np.fill_diagonal(df_spark_res, 0)
```

And this is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Comment: do you wish to fill the entire null values with 0? or just the diagonals ?

Comment: @Vaebhav just the diagonal, because for the other null I need to treat it different

Comment: @Steven I'm sorry, my script didn't reproduce the same error ?